# Index.js file is taking too long to open in React Native

Tags: react-native, silentpush

I am trying to get my React Native app open when a Silent Push Notifiaction is received. I am receiving the Silent Push Notification and the app is also opening when the notification is received. This is how I am getting the notification.
[image: Index file]

On ce i received the notification, I have added a console.log to check whether the app is opening or not. The app is opening correctly, but it is taking aroung 45 seconds to show the console.log.

[image: Index startup] I am receiving this in the terminal 5 seconds after I send the notification. But to receive the console. log and open the app, it is taking aroung 45 seconds.

These are the versions I am using,

`"react-native": "0.64.4",`

`"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.3",`

`"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.3"`

I want the app to open within 10 seconds or 15 maximum.

It would be really helpful if anyone can suggest some solutions. Please comment if any more futrther clarifications needed.

Comment: Create and Test APK, it may be take less time compare to debug.

Comment: @JatinBhuva i tried that too. Taking same amount of time for an APK too